# Access Update Query from one table to another showing all blank records, but expected record count

Tags: ms-access, sql-update, inner-join

When I do an update statement using an inner join to add data from one table to another and I preview the results, it returns 117 blank records. This is the number of records I would expect to be updated, but I'm puzzled why it's blank.

If I do a select statement with the same join with the field from the table with the data and the empty field from the other table, I see the expected results, a populated column and an empty one, but I want the values from ext_complete_employee.Title to be in ext_employee.JobTitle.

```
ext_complete_employee.Title       ext_employee.JobTitle
Poly Tech
Accounting
...
Logistics Coordinator
Skilled Laborer
```

I've been searching and doing variations of the query for a few hours now and can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong -- I must be missing something.

I'm fairly certain that my syntax is correct -- here is the query:

```
    UPDATE ext_employee 
    INNER JOIN ext_complete_employee ON ext_employee.AccountNumber = ext_complete_employee.EmpNum 
    SET ext_employee.JobTitle = ext_complete_employee.Title;
```

Comment: I think what you are seeing is normal for previewing an UPDATE query. Action SQLs are not intended for viewing data. They modify the dataset so what would there be to see?

Comment: You were right -- when I actually executed the query I saw the desired results. It's strange though -- I had done similar action queries where it would give me a preview of what the data would be. With an insert query, if I would view the datasheet view, it would show me the expected results. Running the query would perform the insert. Thanks for the pointer.